Show that $x^4+y^4=z^3$ has no positive integer solution with $(x,y)=1$
I am working on a question from Baker's number theory book's Diophantine equations section for my class. Here is the full question:

Prove that $x^4-3y^4=z^2$ has no solution in positive integers $x,y,z$ and deduce that $x^4+y^4=z^3$ has no such solution with $(x,y)=1$

I managed to show the first part of the question but I can't see how the second part is related to the first part. Could you give me any suggestions?

Welcome to Math SE. Using an Approach0 search, there's Lucas's proof of a special case of Beal's conjecture. Also, FYI, the first part of the full question was asked earlier at proving the equation $x^4-3y^4=z^2$ has no positive integer solutions, where I gave an answer.
